# AutoMapper. Missing type map configuration

Tags: automapper

I have singleton EntityMapper class for Initialize mapper profiles.

```
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private static EntityMapper _instance;
    public static EntityMapper Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new EntityMapper());
    private EntityMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewColumnMapperProfile());
        });
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }
```

In base Profile class:

```
public class BaseMapperProfile<TSorce, TTarget> : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<List<TSorce>, IdentityList>()
            .ForCtorParam("identities", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Identity>(src)));
        CreateMap<IdentityList, List<TSorce>>()
            .ConstructUsing(scr => new List<TSorce>(scr.Select(Mapper.Map<TSorce>)));
    }
}
```

And child class:

```
public class ViewColumnMapperProfile : BaseMapperProfile<AP_ViewColumn, ColumnInfo>
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<AP_ViewColumn, ColumnInfo>()
            .ForMember(...)
        CreateMap<ColumnInfo, AP_ViewColumn>()
            .ForMember(...)

        CreateMap<AP_ViewColumn, Identity>()
            .ForMember(...)
        CreateMap<Identity, AP_ViewColumn>()
            .ForMember(...);

        base.Configure();
    }
}
```

Then I use mapping:

```
    var res = EntityMapper.Map<List<AP_ViewColumn>>(identityList);
```

And this code throws exception: Missing type mao configuration or unsupported mappig.

Mapping types:
  Identity -> AP_ViewColumn

But when I use:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new ViewColumnMapperProfile())); 
var res = EntityMapper.Map<List<AP_ViewColumn>>(identityList);
```

It ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the answer on your question.

When you use `var res = EntityMapper.Map<List<AP_ViewColumn>>(identityList);`, you use your own wrapper which configures and uses the **instance** of `Mapper` class.

However, inside your `BaseMapperProfile` you have a call to static method `Mapper.Map<Identity>(src)`.

But inside your `EntityMapper` you configured/provided all mappings only for **instance** of `Mapper`, **not for** `static Mapper`.

To solve that you need to configure the `static Mapper` by `Mapper.Initialize` method.

For now, I didn't find the way how to pass the mapper instance in there (I think it will be implemented in 5.0 version which is currently in beta).